# Android: How to pass Json data to another activity from Json populated listview

Tags: android, json, listview, android-intent, android-volley

this is my first question on stackoverflow, and I'm kinda new to android (I'm an iOS developer). 
I'm using volley to populate a listview with Json data, now I want to handle the click on a listview item and pass all the data related to the item I clicked, to a new activity. How can I do that? Here is my "MainActivity" that I called "MenuActivity". Thanks in advance for your help ^^.

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
JSONArray contact = null;
private String urlJsonObj = "http://advadwords.it/Hotel_managing_app/index.php/Controller_managing_app/json_menu";
private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
//private String jsonResponse;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
ListView lv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Sto caricando...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    makeJsonObjectRequest();


}
private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {
    pDialog.show();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
            urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            try {
                contact = response.getJSONArray("menu");
                for (int i = 0; i < contact.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject details = (JSONObject) contact.get(i);
                    String giorno = details.getString("Giorno");
                    String pranzoPrimo = details.getString("Pranzo_primo");

                    HashMap<String, String> contct = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    contct.put("Giorno", giorno);
                    contct.put("Pranzo_primo", pranzoPrimo);

                    contactList.add(contct);


                    //adapter to set response in textview
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            MenuActivity.this, contactList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"Giorno", "Pranzo_primo"}, new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.primoPranzo});
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            hidepDialog();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // hide the progress dialog
            hidepDialog();
        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
}
private void showpDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}
private void hidepDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> I want to handle the click on a listview item and pass all the data
>   related to the item I clicked, to a new activity.

You have to implement `onItemClickListener` in your listView. When list clicked, pass the ID to another activity and finally retrieved all the data which belongs to ID in the activity.

```
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                HashMap<String, String> clickedItem = contactList.get(position);
                ID=clickedItem.get(Configs.TAG_ID); // your key ID
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Edit"+ID,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
                intent.putExtra("ID", ID); // pass the ID to another activity
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I've tried to copy this code into the onCreate method, but it gives me a couple of errors. The first one in "lvt.get(position);", the second one in Configs.TAG_ID

Comment: yes,because I just give you some hints. Would you mind to tell me the error ?

Comment: It says "Cannot resolve method get(int)" and "Cannot resolve symbol Configs"

Comment: The Configs you have to change ...what is the key you used for ID ?

Comment: The key is called "id".

Comment: ID=clickedItem.get("id");